# Centre of mass row-wise in a dataframe and multiply each column by different mass

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I'm trying to calculate the centre of mass of 20 objects, where each object has it's own different mass.

These objects are represented in a dataframe `cm_x`, and their associated masses in a list. Below I show an example of just 3 of those 20 objects, for the sake of saving space. Each object has an `x, y, z` coordinate, but I'll just show the `x` and then I can apply the same technique to the rest. Below is the head of the dataframe.

```
bar_head_x  bar_hip_centre_x    bar_left_ankle_x
0   -203.3502   -195.4573   -293.262
1   -203.4280   -195.4720   -293.251
2   -203.4954   -195.4675   -293.248
3   -203.5022   -195.9193   -293.219
4   -203.5014   -195.9092   -293.328

m_head = 0.081
m_hipc = 0.139
m_lank = 0.0465
m = [m_head,m_hipc,m_lank]
```

I saw in another similar question, someone has suggested this method, however this doesn't incorporate the masses, and that is where I'm having an issue:

```
def series_sum(pd_series):
    return np.sum(np.dot(pd_series.values, np.asarray(range(1, len(pd_series)+1)))/np.sum(pd_series))

cm_x.apply(series_sum, axis=1)
```

Basically I want for each row, to have an associated centre of mass, using the formula for centre of mass which is `sum(x_i * m_i) / sum(m_i)`.

The desired result would be a new column in the dataframe like so:

```
cm_x
0   -214.92
1   ...
2   ...
3   ...
4   ...
```

Any help?

Comment: Please make small sample dataframes, 6 rows max, and show the result you want.

Comment: @timgeb I made the edits.

Comment: Thanks. I don't undertand where the `-316.710` comes from. Shouldn't the first value be `(-203.3502*0.081 + (-195.4573)*0.139 + (-293.262)*0.0465) / (0.081 + 0.139 + 0.0465) ~ -214.92`?

Comment: @timgeb yes sorry, I must have missed a sign when doing the calculation, you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can compute the desired column like this:

```
>>> df.mul(m).sum(axis=1)/sum(m)
0   -214.921628
1   -214.951023
2   -214.968638
3   -215.201292
4   -215.214800
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) and divide by `sum` of list `m`:

```
s = df.dot(m).div(sum(m))
print (s)
0      -214.921628
1      -214.951023
2      -214.968638
3      -215.201292
4      -215.214800
7441   -245.078910
7442   -244.943961
7443   -244.806606
7444   -244.665285
7445   -244.533503
dtype: float64
```

If need `DataFrame` add [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df1 = df.dot(m).div(sum(m)).to_frame('cm_x')
print (df1)
            cm_x
0    -214.921628
1    -214.951023
2    -214.968638
3    -215.201292
4    -215.214800
7441 -245.078910
7442 -244.943961
7443 -244.806606
7444 -244.665285
7445 -244.533503
```

Comment: for me both are equally as simple

Comment: @Oam - Honestly, for people who dont use/know `dot` then `mul` with `sum` is better understable, but `dot` here is simplier.

Comment: I didn't even know `dot`. I'll certainly use it in the future.

Comment: @timgeb - ya, I like it ;)